# Padding zip() with undefined

Tags: rxjs

The following

```
Rx.Observable.zip(
     Rx.Observable.of(1,2),
     Rx.Observable.of("a"))
  .subscribe(p => console.log(p))
```

produces

```
1,a
```

which makes sense, but what I want it to produce is

```
1,a
2,undefined
```

I want to pad the shorter observable with undefineds until the longer one completes.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Are the synchronous observables in question representative of the use case? The problem is that `combineLatest` cannot be used as the core of a composed observable if the solution must work with observables that emit synchronously. That is, using the question's observables with `combineLatest` sees a single value emitted: `[2, "a"]`.

Comment: @cartant -- in my actual use, it's likely that one will be synchronous and the other coming from I/O, but I would like a fully general solution.

Answer (score 1):

I realise adding delay can turn the .of operator async and with scan you can replace the same value with undefine

```
Rx.Observable.combineLatest(
 Rx.Observable.of(1,2).delay(0),
 Rx.Observable.of("a"))
 .scan((acc,curr)=>{
    acc[1]=acc[1]==curr[1]?undefined:curr[1]
    acc[0]=acc[0]==curr[0]?undefined:curr[0]
return acc
 },[])
 .subscribe(p => console.log(p))
```

Comment: I also thought that `combineLatest` could be used to solve the problem - it works with the example data in the question because the second source observable emits only one value. However, if the observables each emit multiple values, the output won't be like that of `zip`.

Comment: Maybe i should eidt the answer as well

Answer (score 1):

I think the key to this is to ensure that all of the source observables are the same length.

One solution would be to compose a counter observable that's as long as the longest source observable. It could then be concatenated to the shorter source observables, like this:

```js
const pad = (...sources) => Rx.Observable.create(observer => {

  // Publish the source observables to make them multicast
  // and to allow the subscription order to be managed.

  const publishedSources = sources.map(source => source.publish());

  // Create an observable that emits an incremented index and
  // is as long as the longest source observable.

  const counter = Rx.Observable
    .merge(...publishedSources.map(
      source => source.map((unused, index) => index)
    ))
    .scan((max, index) => Math.max(max, index), 0)
    .distinctUntilChanged()
    .publish();

  // Zip the published sources, contatenating the counter so
  // that they are all the same length. When the counter
  // emissions are concatenated, they are mapped to undefined.

  const subscription = Rx.Observable.zip(...publishedSources.map(
    source => source.concat(counter.mapTo(undefined))
  )).subscribe(observer);

  // Connect the counter and the published sources.

  subscription.add(counter.connect());
  publishedSources.forEach(
    source => subscription.add(source.connect())
  );
  return subscription;
});

pad(
  Rx.Observable.of(1, 2),
  Rx.Observable.of("a")
).subscribe(padded => console.log(padded));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs@5/bundles/Rx.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

My own solution is below.  The idea is that all the observables are converted into endless streams, starting with the original values, enclosed in objects, and then an infinite number of undefineds.  These endless streams are concatted and the result is taken as long as any of the values are original.

```js
const unending = (obs) => 
  obs.map(value => ({value}))
     .concat(Rx.Observable
               .interval(0)
               .mapTo(undefined));

const zipPad = (...obss) => 
  Rx.Observable.zip(...obss.map(unending))
    .takeWhile(p => p.find(v => v))
    .map(p => p.map(v => v && v.value));

zipPad(Rx.Observable.of(1,2,3),
       Rx.Observable.of("a"),
       Rx.Observable.of("x", "y"))
.subscribe(p => console.log(p));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.5.6/Rx.min.js"></script>
```

Anyone is welcome to improve on this answer and post their variations here.