# Rxjs: zip two observes with unequal lengths

Tags: rxjs

I would like to zip two observes.
I tried to zip them, but it returns [6,9], [10,8], [40,4], [33,2].

```
let source1 = of(6, 10, 40, 33);
let source2 = of(9, 8, 4, 2, 3);
let final = zip(source1, source2);
final.subscribe(x=>console.log(x));
```

My expected output is [6,9], [10,8], [40,4], [33,2], ["",3].
How can I zip  two observes with unequal lengths?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You are already doing it. What would be the expected behavior?

Comment: No. ["",3] is not returned.

Answer (score 0):

The `zip` function of RxJS can only merge emissions of observables that _dud occur and it will stop when the "smallest" observable stops emitting. So, what you're looking at is expected behavior. The easiest solution would be to ensure that both observables are of the same length, e.g. by adding a `0` or `undefined` to the end of `source1`:

```
let source1 = of(6, 10, 40, 33, 0);
let source2 = of(9, 8, 4, 2, 3);
let final = zip(source1, source2);
final.subscribe(x=>console.log(x));
```

If you cannot do that and need a more complex solution, take a look at this related question: [Padding zip() with undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48103670/padding-zip-with-undefined)

Answer (score 0):

```js
let source1 = of(6, 10, 40, 33);
let source2 = of(9, 8, 4, 2, 3);
let final = zip(source1, source2);
final.subscribe(x=>console.log(x));
```

I don't think this is possible with `zip`. The way it works is that for each provided source, it will create an array, and that array will be added to a buffer, such that when a source emits, its value will be added to the buffer [as follows](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/observable/zip.ts#L209):

```js
/* ... */

buffers[sourceIndex].push(value);

/* ... */
```

Now, in order for `zip` to emit an array of values, this condition must be matched:

```js
/* ... */
if (buffers.every((buffer) => buffer.length))  { }
/* ... */
```

In other words, every source's array must have at least one value. This is not that case when `source2` emits `3`.

---

A way to solve this might be to use `combineLatest` instead:

```js
combineLatest(
  source1$.pipe(map((v, idx) => ({ v, idx }))), 
  source2$.pipe(map((v, idx) => ({ v, idx }))),
).pipe(
  scan((prevArr, crtArr) => {
    const [prev1, prev2] = prevArr;
    let [crt1, crt2] = crtArr;

    // if there is not a newer value
    prev1.idx === crt1.idx && (crt1.v = '');
    prev2.idx === crt2.idx && (crt2.v = '');

    return [crt1, crt2];
  }, [{}, {}]),
  
  // filtering out the index
  map((arr) => arr.map(({ v }) => v)),

  switchMap(
    (valuesArr) => of(valuesArr).pipe(
      // if the array does not contain empty string values,
      // it means both sources emitted something new
      // and it that's the case, then we should send the array of values immediately 
      // ((obs$) => obs$ is the identity function)
      // otherwise we use `debounceTime(0)` to wait until the sources stop sending values synchronously 
      // or not sending any values at all
      valuesArr.every(v => !!v) ? (obs$) => obs$ : debounceTime(0)
    )
  )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a very simple solution for this, however, it's predicated on 2 conditions:

1. You always know which stream will be the shorter/longer one;
2. It's acceptable for you to have the shorter stream repeat from the start and emit the same values (instead of an empty string).

If this is acceptable, you can use the `repeatWhen` operator. For example:

```
let final = zip(source1.pipe(repeatWhen(() => source2), source2));
```

The above code hasn't been tested, but I'm using a similar solution and it seems to work fine. As the name implies, the "shorter" source will cycle back to the start and continue to emit values as long as the "longer" source is emitting and hasn't completed.

This is the key point, and from here you can probably add more fine-grained controls to modify the repeated values so they return an empty string instead.