# RxJs (typescript) transpose

Tags: typescript, rxjs

Currently i'm working on a very simple way of transposing object arrays (in this scenario strings) in RX.JS.

The code is currently like this :

```
const observableArray = [from(["A1", "A2", "A3"]),from(["B1", "B2"]),from(["C1", "C2","C3"])];
const source$ = zip(...observableArray);
const myTask = source$.pipe(mergeMap(x=>x),toArray()).toPromise();
.....
```

and the output is : [ 'A1', 'B1', 'C1', 'A2', 'B2', 'C2' ] as expected due to the behaviour of the zip operator (and the first completion of the observable which containing the B... array).

But what i want to achieve is that all the elements are transposed : like this : [ 'A1', 'B1', 'C1', 'A2', 'B2', 'C2' , 'A3', 'C3' ] (waiting till all observables are completed)

Any ideas?

I'm able to do this by making all array sizes the same (with null objects) and in the last step filter them out, but I'm really wondering if I could do this in a more RXJS way

Thanx in advance,

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64416273/rxjs-zip-two-observes-with-unequal-lengths

Comment: thanx, not using the correct search keys